# Convolution - references request

Tags: functional-analysis, reference-request, fourier-analysis, fourier-series, fourier-transform

From which book this chapter is ? http://www.math.ncku.edu.tw/~rchen/2016%20Teaching/Chapter%203_Convolution.pdf

Comment: Please try to make the titles of your questions more informative. For example, *Why does $a<b$ imply $a+c<b+c$?* is much more useful for other users than *A question about inequality.* From [How can I ask a good question?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/589/): *Make your title as descriptive as possible. In many cases one can actually phrase the title as the question, at least in such a way so as to be comprehensible to an expert reader.* You can find more tips for choosing a good title [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10144/).

Comment: I don't know. However, look at the URL closely. It's from a university with initials NCKU in a country with English initials TW. The "RChen" is a strong hint as to who wrote the notes. From this information, you are likely to find the general page the link is from, and from there, the book you're after. Good luck! --- EDIT: See [here](http://www.math.ncku.edu.tw/~rchen/) to get you started.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be a chapter from Brad Osgood's lecture notes on "The Fourier Transform and Its Applications", Course EE261 at Stanford. More material, including video recording of lectures, is available on the [course website](https://see.stanford.edu/course/ee261).

Comment: So it says on the first page of http://www.math.ncku.edu.tw/~rchen/2016%20Teaching/Chapter%201_Fourier%20Series .pdf, too.